# The best way to remove duplicate strings in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, lodash

We have managed to create the script below to remove any duplicate strings from an array. However, it is important that we keep the order of the array for when angular loops through them on an ng-repeat. In addition, we want the remaining elements to keep the same index.

```
scope.feedback = _.map(_.pluck(item.possibleAnswers, 'feedback'), function (element, index, collection) {
    return collection.slice(0, index).indexOf(element) === -1 ? element : '';
});
```

This code above works however we feel like there must be a more simple solution to our problem than this. Has anyone else had a similar problem and come up with a better solution?

Comment: how about using reduce for same purpose? here's the fiddle with numbers instead of strings, but I don't think it should matter https://jsfiddle.net/58z7nrfy/

Comment: You're looking after array of strings or array of any? Can you add some use cases or any example of what are you about (something like before and after).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variant with reduce https://jsfiddle.net/58z7nrfy/1/

```
var a = [1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,3,4,5,5,12,1,23,4,1];

var b = a.reduce(function(p,c,i,a){
  if (p.indexOf(c) == -1) p.push(c);
  else p.push('')
  return p;
}, [])
console.log(b)
```

> [1, 2, 3, "", "", "", "", "", "", 4, 5, "", 12, "", 23, "", ""]

Comment: Your way is slightly faster so thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

If the target browsers support [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator$edit#Browser_compatibility) then try in your console:

```
[...new Set(['3','1','1','5'])]
// ['3','1','5']
```

Or if browser support [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from$edit#Browser_compatibility) you could also write:

```
Array.from(new Set(['3','1','1','5']))
// ['3','1','5']
```

Comment: So this would work but I need to keep the length of the array the same..

Comment: @MaxLynn how you can keep same lenght if you removed values from it?

Comment: Guys you need to read the question in more depth. We need to keep the order of the array so we know what ones don't need any text. Which is why in the script we replace the duplicate with a empty string

Comment: @MaxLynn just add `else p.push('')` - updated my example. is that it?

Comment: I see it now from your code, but in the text you never mention that you need to replace the strings with an empty ones

Comment: @MaxLynn but I doubt any code will be shorter or simpler that the one you have already. Actually my code even if compacted to one string is probably already longer...

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the answers mentioned, you can also use [lodash union](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#union) function like this:

```
let duplicates = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Hello'];
let uniques = _.union(duplicates);
```

Uniques will be: ["Hello", "Hi"]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which is type prove and prevents iterating again and again with [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 12, 1, 23, 4, 1, '23'],
    filtered = a.filter(function (a) {
        if (!this.has(a)) {
            this.set(a, true);
            return true;
        }
    }, new Map);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Your answer handle same number and string number as different items , Is that what you want? BTW I didn't get OP's request at all.

Comment: @mortezaT, maybe, i don't know either :)

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is very inefficient. One could use reduce and a hash table or map object to boost the performance. Here I would prefer map in the place of reduce though. Yet I guess extending @Nina Scholz's approach by doubling the maps, the proper answer to OP's question is as follows;

```js
var   a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 12, 1, 23, 4, 1, '23'],
unified = a.map(function(e) {
                  return this.has(e) ? void 0 : (this.set(e,"Cheap Thrills"),e);
                }, new Map());
console.log(unified);
```

If this would be a production code with an arbitrary length array then rather than going with functors, i would implement the map method with standard functions though since it introduces an additional serious performance boost in large arrays. (like in size 10K+)

Answer (score 1):

i think lodash `uniq()` is very helpful

```
let data = [1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,3,4,5,5,12,1,23,4,1];
let uniqData = _.uniq(data ,(e) => {
 return e;
});
```

then output will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this script:

```
var words = ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'two'];
    var result = [];
    for(i=0;i<words.length;i++){
      if(result.indexOf(words[i]) == -1){
        result.push(words[i])
      }
    }
```