# Remove duplicate from array while mapping

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping, jsx

Is it possible to remove array duplicates inside of a map function. I'm using Jsx and I have an array of strings, I would like to be as straight forward as possible, but if I have to I will go a different way. I'll show you the code. If you have any suggestions, it is appreciated.

```
<aside>
    {tags.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(item.node.category)
    let set = []
    set.push(item.node.category)
    let mine = new Set(set) //this was my poor attempt
    console.log(mine)
    return (
    <>
    <Link
    key={index}
    to={`/blog/categoria/${item.node.category.trim()}`}
    className="category"
    >
    {item.node.category}
    </Link>
    </>
    )
    })}
</aside>
```

Comment: Mapping is a 1:1 operation. If you want to remove items, you need `.filter()` and then follow it up with `.map()` over the filtered data. You can combine both in a `.reduce()` if you want a single pass through the array.

Comment: Remove duplicate questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373364/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-strings-in-an-array

Comment: Now we talking. You know if it doesn't happen to be my own stuff I never understand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The best way to remove duplicate strings in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373364/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-strings-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

There was a way of removing duplicates of the array while mapping through it, and that was using lodash `_.uniq()` but I didn't do it this way. I (stupid me) had to first grab the array I was interested in

```
 let tagsonly = []

  let tags = data.allDatoCmsBlog.edges

  tags.forEach(element => {
    tagsonly.push(element.node.category)
  })
```

and then went with a reduce function

```
 var tagssorted = tagsonly.reduce(function (p, c, i, a) {
    if (p.indexOf(c) == -1) p.push(c)
    else p.push(null)
    return p
  }, [])
```

tagssorted is what I wanted